# How do I connect a laptop to both a wireless LAN and a wi-fi hotspot?

Tags: networking, windows-8, wireless-networking, router, tethering

I have two networks at my home -- a LAN where I'd like to share my files, and a phone that provides my only Internet via a wi-fi hotspot feature. Hoping to access both at once, I outfitted my Windows 8 laptop with a second network adapter.

Unfortunately, as soon as I try connecting to the LAN, every request for a webpage bounces off the LAN router, and fails. The order I connect to these two wi-fi networks doesn't seem to change this problem.

What do I do to remedy the situation? Is there some way to change which network is used for Internet connectivity? I can configure my router, but probably not my wi-fi hotspot.

Comment: @jjlin I believe the circumstances between these two questions are different (I don't know the LAN IP addresses I'd like to connect to, and the answers here and there look like day-and-night differences to uneducated me), but I'll take a look in case the answer here doesn't work :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit: Currently, your Home WLAN's internet gateway takes precedence over your hot spot.

The reason this is happening is that both network connections, your two wireless lan's, have a default gateway and Windows only recognises **one** as the default gatewaym hence "default."

Try:
Go to Start, type "ncpa.cpl" (no quotes), and hit Enter. On the Network Connections dialogue, hit Alt (to expose the menu bar), go to Advanced->Advanced Settings, and you’ll see a list of network connections. Make sure your Phone's hot-spot connected adapter is listed first. Save and reboot.

[image: Steps]

Comment: Novice user > simple answer. Thanks for following the KISS principle.